# How can I change the size of the CheckBox image of LibGdx?

Tags: java, libgdx

I'm using the skin from libgdx tests: uiskin.json.

For some reason the checkbox is displayed much smaller as f.e. in badlogic/gdx/tests/MipMapTest.java
What does the size of the Checkbox depend on? the camera's resolution? Or is there a way to set it manually?

Helper.RESOLUTION_WIDTH = 800 and

Helper.RESOLUTION_HEIGHT = 1280

```
@Override
public void show() {

    skin = new Skin(Gdx.files.internal("skins/uiskin.json"));
    cam = new OrthographicCamera(Helper.RESOLUTION_WIDTH, Helper.RESOLUTION_HEIGHT);
    cam.position.set(Helper.RESOLUTION_WIDTH / 2, Helper.RESOLUTION_HEIGHT / 2, 0); 
    stage = new Stage(Helper.RESOLUTION_WIDTH, Helper.RESOLUTION_HEIGHT, true);
    stage.setCamera(cam);

    CheckBox checkBox1 = new CheckBox("", skin);
    checkBox1.addListener(new ChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void changed(ChangeEvent event, Actor actor) {
            game.setScreen(new WinScreen2a(game));
        }
    });
    CheckBox checkBox2 = new CheckBox("", skin);
    checkBox2.addListener(new ChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void changed(ChangeEvent event, Actor actor) {
            game.setScreen(new WinScreen2b(game));
        }
    });

    Window window = new Window("Dialog", skin);
    window.debug();
    window.setPosition(Helper.RESOLUTION_WIDTH/2 - 375, 10);
    window.setSize(750, 350);

    table.add(checkBox1).left();
    table.getCells().get(0).size(200, 100);
    table.add(option1).width(500).height(100).pad(10f);
    table.row();

    table.add(checkBox2).left();
    table.getCells().get(2).size(200, 100);
    table.add(option2).width(500).height(100).pad(10f);
    table.row();

    window.add(table).top().left();
    stage.addActor(window);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set image scaling type. Default is none.

```
CheckBox soundCB = new CheckBox("Sound", uiskin);
soundCB.getImage().setScaling(Scaling.fill);
soundCB.getImageCell().size(GameConfig.WIDTH/6);
soundCB.left().pad(PAD);
soundCB.getLabelCell().pad(PAD);
//...
content.add(soundCB).width(GameConfig.WIDTH/1.5f).row(); //add to table
```

Answer (score 0):

This changes the checkbox image size, but I noticed that the click detection is not accurate then. Couldn't change that with setting the bounds of the box, but maybe there is still some way yet to be discovered.

```
CheckBox cb = new CheckBox(" Label text", xxx.getDefaultSkin());
// Changes the checkbox image size
cb.getImageCell().height(50);
cb.getImageCell().width(50);
// Change the text size accordingly
cb.getLabel().setFontScale(0.6f, 0.6f);
```

My thoughs though are that it may be nicer to create a custom component for this => Create a class that **extends Actor**. The class wraps an image button with a label. Then add helper methods to easily modify the component as needed.
This way I have had success in creating complex easily reusable components that look neat.